# How can I use `If` condition in `Resources` of `serverless.yml`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am trying to use `!If` condition in `resources` section but failed. I'd like to control whether to set `provisionedConcurrency` on my lambda. The lambda is defined under `function` section.

```yaml
functions:
  getTransactionsHandler:
    ...

resources:
  Conditions:
    CommonPCNotZero: !Not [!Equals [0, '${self:custom.commonPC}']]
  Resources:
    !If 
      - CommonPCNotZero
      - getTransactionsHandler:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
          Properties:
            FunctionName: !Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction
            FunctionVersion: !Join ['', [!Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction, ':$LATEST']]
            ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
              ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: '${self:custom.commonPC}'
      - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

I got below error when run `sls deploy`:

```
Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: [/Resources/Fn::If] resource definition is malformed
```

what is the right way to use `!if` condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a resource, you just add a `Condition` to include or exclude it.

```yaml
functions:
  getTransactionsHandler:
    ...

resources:
  Conditions:
    CommonPCNotZero: !Not [!Equals [0, '${self:custom.commonPC}']]
  Resources:
    getTransactionsHandler:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
      Condition: CommonPCNotZero
      Properties:
        FunctionName: !Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction
        FunctionVersion: !Join ['', [!Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction, ':$LATEST']]
        ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
          ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: '${self:custom.commonPC}'
```

Also, watch your indentation. `Type` and `Properties` should be at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make entire resource conditional using If. Normally, the following should be done using [Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-condition.html):

```
resources:
  Conditions:
    CommonPCNotZero: !Not [!Equals [0, '${self:custom.commonPC}']]
  Resources:
     
     MyLambdaAlias: 
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Alias
        Condition: CommonPCNotZero
        Properties:
            FunctionName: !Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction
            FunctionVersion: !Join ['', [!Ref GetTransactionsHandlerLambdaFunction, ':$LATEST']]
            ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
              ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: '${self:custom.commonPC}'
```